# Pandas Rolling using where breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to compute the standard deviation of positive numbers.

```
np.random.seed(42)
d = pd.Series(data = np.random.randn(1000))
```

if I do the following:

```
(d.where(d>0))[-100:].std(skipna=True)
```

I get `0.56972171400539895`
But if I try to us the rolling functions I only get `nan`:

```
(d.where(d>0)).rolling(100).std(skipna=True).iloc[-1]
```

Is there a way to make that rolling function work?
I've tested with python 3.5 and pandas 0.20

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use `where`  instead of boolean indexing? For example, for a window of 3, `[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4]`  what would your standard deviation be? std([1, 2, 3]) (the first three positives) or std([1, 2]) (positives of the first three elements).

Comment: I'm using it for time series (hence the rolling function). So in your example, for index -1, the window of 3 would look at the std([nan, 4, nan]), while the index 0 would look at std([1, nan, 2]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand how the rolling window works. The window size we provide is the size of the consecutive elements on which the stats will be computed. If any element is NaN, then average will be NaN. For e.g.
Let `d.where(d>0)` is

```
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5     0.384464
6     0.384464
7     0.275835
8     0.414436
9     0.414436
10    0.428174
...
```

Now if I provide rolling window as 100, then first 99 element will always be NaN, along with all those window in which there is even a single NaN.

One way to counter this is to provide value to argument min_period which is Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value.

so if I do `d.where(d>0).rolling(100,min_periods=2).std()`, I get:

```
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5     0.384464
6     0.384464
7     0.275835
8     0.414436
9     0.414436
10    0.428174
...
```

Note here than till index 4 all values are NaN, since minimum values aren't met. After that in the window size of 100, there is at least 2 values,hence values are populated.

Comment: Thanks. In a sense I was expecting the `rolling` method to be like a for loop over the indexes, and as such the function applied to behave the same.